# Internet Explorer Caching Flash SWF Problem

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, caching

I’m having a problem with Internet Explorer caching a URL variable. I have a list of links:

1. videorecorder.php?filename=12345"
2. videorecorder.php?filename=123456"
3. videorecorder.php?filename=123457

The variable is use for the video. I have tried everything here far but not luck. Tried this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0">
```

It seem that the first variable pass in persist any subsequent filename variable are get ignored.

Here is the link http://codedecks.com/recorder/ to try it for yourself.  Any suggestion would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a caching problem. Try DeveloperToolbar and disable cache and it will work fine. Try embedding your swf with a unique URL like `videorecorder.swf?c=someUniqeValue`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your response! I disable cache in DeveloperToolbar in IE 9 and it worked like a charm. Is the a permanent fix or will user have to do the same? What about IE 7 and 8, there no DeveloperToolbar ?

Comment: The user will have to do the same. this is not an option you should implement like is advised in my post. If you append a unique parameter to your swf url the swf will not be cached.

Comment: I actually did append a unique parameter at the end of my .swf file [param name="movie" value="videorecorder.swf?UniqeValue=869412345"] and [embed src="videorecorder.swf?UniqeValue=869412345"...].

Comment: I've tried that already but just tried it again as you've suggested. Still no luck.=( any other suggestion?

Comment: mhm, see that in source code but the request goes out without that parameter. strange. Try to embed your swf with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Comment: Daniel, I tried using swfobject to embed but still the same error. I'm just going have the user disable cache us you had suggested.